# edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull doesn't throw error with null params

Tags: annotations, findbugs

I have the following

```
void testFunc(@NonNull String param1, @NonNull String param2) {

}
```

When I invoke this method with null parameters from a Junit test case, the test suceeds
   testFunc(null, "testString");

This should be throwing an error instead. Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No, it shouldn‘t. But when you run a FindBugs analysis on your invocation, it should be flagged.

Comment: In that case what would be the best way to add null conditions for a method with several params. Using com.google.common.base.Preconditions is one of the clean ways to add such conditions. But would be too many checks for the above use case. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.